# Построение предложения. Грамотная речь

Tags: грамотная-речь

Добрый день.

Столкнулся с предложением и не могу определить корректно ли оно.

1) Вместе с вошедшим кондуктором, (?) из пыльной дымки улицы  в салон автобуса залетел шмель. ( Можно ли считать первую часть уточнением? ( приложение)
2) Вслед за кондуктором, (?) из пыльной дымки улицы в салон автобуса залетел шмель. ( Каким правилом пользоваться?)

Comment: "Из пыльной дымкЕ"?) Сначала поправьте ошибку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Неудачная для чтения структура  предложения:** три обстоятельства перед предикативной основой.

1) После редактирования:

Из пыльной дымки улицы, **вслед за кондуктором**, в салон автобуса залетел шмель.

Из пыльной дымки улицы, **вместе с вошедшим кондуктором**, в салон автобуса залетел шмель.

В этом случае второе обстоятельство обособляется со значением уточнения.

2) В приведенном варианте в начале предложения можно обособить **распространенное обстоятельство** (детерминант), отнесенное ко всему предложению, например: Вслед за вошедшим на остановке кондуктором, в салон автобуса неожиданно залетел большой золотистый шмель.

Таким образом, **для обособления оборота пришлось распространить и сам оборот, и  всё предложение.**

В общем случае обособление подобных конструкций является **факультативным** и зависит от распространенности оборота, от его позиции, от стиля предложения.